# AndroidStudio -> Enable Annotationprocessing in Editor (lombok)

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, lombok

I'm trying to use lombok in my Android Studio but i don't know how to enable AnnotationProcessing in AS/Gradle for the Editor.

Thanks for help,
Benny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the Lombok plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317?pr=idea